# How to retrieve data from this XML using JQuery OR any other java scripting method

Tags: jquery, xml

I just come across with some strange situation. I want to traverse this strange XML using jQuery.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
   <CategorySearch id="132801">
      <Category id="132801" name="ABC">
        <Category id="100327623" name="DEF">
          <Category id="133101" name="GHI" /> 
          <Category id="133501" name="KLM" /> 
        </Category>
      <Category id="100327523" name="NOP">
        <Category id="133401" name="QRS"/> 
      </Category>
      <Category id="100291623">
        <Category id="132701" /> 
        <Category id="147501" /> 
        <Category id="133901" /> 
      </Category>
     <Category id="134201">
       <Category id="100250023" /> 
       <Category id="100477023" /> 
     </Category>
     <Category id="133601">
       <Category id="100046513" /> 
       <Category id="100532023" /> 
       <Category id="133001" /> 
     </Category>
  </Category>
 </CategorySearch>
```

For Example,

If i give name attribute to the above XML. So output should be like,

```
ABC
 DEF
 GHI
 KLM
NOP
 QRS
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't see why that's strange XML, unless you're referring to the capitalisation of the tags, and the rather sporadic indentation used.

Comment: If you see it has child nodes with the same name as parent node. How can i parse this with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd Googled it, you would have happily come accross [`.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

> jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to
>   create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to
>   jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and
>   manipulated.

Comment: i m already using parseXML method. but the point in this xml is it has all the nodes with same name.

Comment: Does `.parseXML()` give you an error, or incorrect output? Try printing the generated XML to the page and use Firebug (or whatever) to inspect it. You're not telling us what errors you're getting

Comment: Actually i m not getting any error. I am just confused because the parent and the child has the same name. I want to show it in a tree view after parsing it. i am using Category.each but it just giving me simple output, i want to generate output like parent child separately. i hope i made it understand.

Comment: Zee, you caused the confusion by saying you were having trouble parsing the XML. In fact, it seems you have no trouble parsing the XML, your difficulty is in processing it after it has been parsed. Unfortunately this misuse of the term "parsing" is very common, but it does cause confusion. I'm afraid I can't answer your question because I don't know jQuery.

Comment: @Michael Kay, Thanks for pointing me that i have Edited my Question.